# How to control animated gif speed when exporting from Premier Pro

Tags: premiere, animation, adobe, adobe-media-encoder, export

I have got a sequence of 25 frames from a series of photos that I shot. I have imported the images into Premiere Pro and changed the speed/duration to 00.00.02.

When I preview the sequence in the preview window, it runs at the exact speed I want it. However, when I export it as an animated gif the file runs at about 1 frame per second which is too slow.

How do I control the speed when I export the .gif file?

Answer (score 1):

when you are exporting you should be able to change the frame rate in the basic video setting. If you "un-check" the box of the preset option, you can select the rate between different values.